# Set the display of Unicode filenames in Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, unicode

I have a folder on Windows that contains files whose name contain unicode extended characters (simplified chinese). I'd like to grab a list of these files. Of course, cmd won't display them correctly, but I was hoping Powershell could.

Unfortunately, the result of the dir command isn't any better. When I search existing questions, everything is about the file encoding, not displaying the file name.

I'm not looking to make any system-wide change like changing the system locale or the default code-page, but I would expect PowerShell to be able to handle unicode output on screen.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

R.

Comment: Do you have access to PowerShell ISE? Is that an option?

Comment: Indeed, I never imagined that it would work in ISE but not in PowerShell! Thanks!